# event receiver not firing event after multiple documents uploaded into document library in item updated event

Tags: event-receivers

I have  an event receiver.On item updated event i am firing email.condition is like this: I have an document library with two Yes/No columns(i.e Notification & IsActive).If both these conditions are true ,then email will trigger.Its working fine.On item adding event i am changing value of IsActive column to false.It is also working fine.But when I am uploading multiple documents to document library email is not triggerring.I debugged and saw that debugger is not going to the send mail method.If any body knows pls guide.

Comment: When you debug event receiver, does it hit your breakpoint when trying to upload multiple files?

Comment: Maybe you could show us some code, so it becomes clearer how your implementation looks like and what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

If your library is configured to require checking out files, your event receiver only fires after an item is updated which happens after item check-in. When you upload multiple documents, the event is not fired until the change is checked in.

You may have more luck with the ItemUpdating. This may fire before the check-in.

You can review the full list of events [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff408183%28v=office.14%29.aspx) and also the order of ItemCheckedIn and ItemUpdated events [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventreceiver.itemcheckedin(v=office.14).aspx).